# Save an HTML resume as a PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a resume that I've made in HTML, but I need to make it into a PDF. I could print it and then scan it, but I don't have that option at the moment.
The website is made using HTML, CSS3, and very little javascript.
I've tried using HTML to PDF converters, but my fonts don't show up and some other things don't work out.
So simply put, is there a way I can save it while keeping all the styles?

Comment: Did you try Control + P, pick save as pdf and save it?

Comment: Do you want to do this _programmatically_? If not, try asking on superuser.com, this place is about programming.

Comment: Thanks, for the most part it works.

Comment: And thg435, i'd actually love to know how to make a save as button, but i've only found out how to do it in IE. Making a print button is easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firefox's Print to File option and change the printer settings like below (especially the "Header and Footer" setting, you can come up with a pretty decent result.

[image]

The result:
[image]

Comment: You may find this repository useful: https://github.com/hasukmistry/html-cv-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you install some PDF software like [Foxit PDF creator](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/), you can `print` your webpage as a PDF